# Matching and eliminating elements of a vector of doubles

Tags: matlab, vector

I have an input vector like:

```
[1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1]
```

I would then like to check whether x.1 and x.2 and x.3 and x.y is in the vector and then discard if there isn't at least 3 y values with matching x values exist. So the example vector would look like:

```
[2.2, 2.3, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 5.2, 3.1]
```

(`1.3`, `1.1`, and `4.2` are removed due to only 2 and 1 x value). It has to work for a vector of any length. I just started to try learn Matlab from a guide but I simply cant complete this question :(

Comment: Post the code of what you have tried so far...

Comment: Can there be values with other fractional parts, such as `1.4`? What's the criterion then?

Comment: @Luis Mendo Yes if there is more then 3 y values then the values should be in the new vector. Dan im kinda from the scratch dunno how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

1. Compute the integer part of `x`;
2. Count how may times each obtained integer part occurs, and to each value of `x` associate its corresponding number of times;
3. Keep only the values of `x` whose integer part occurs at least `n=3` times.

Code:

```
x = [1.3 2.2 2.3 4.2 5.1 3.2 5.3 3.3 2.1 1.1 5.2 3.1]; %// data
n = 3;                                                 %// min required number
xf = floor(x);                                         %// step 1
[ii, jj] = histc(xf, unique(xf));                      %// step 2
result = x(ismember(jj, find(ii>=n)));                 %// step 3
```